# Remove a user from user profiles

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, user-profile, azure

If i remove a user from the user profiles in sharepoint online. Can i restore or sync it again from azure ad? Or will it remove the user completely?

Answer (score 2):

> When you delete a user account, the account becomes inactive. However, for approximately 30 days after you have deleted it, you can restore the account and the associated data.
>
> If your organization synchronizes user accounts to Office 365 from a local Active Directory environment, you must delete and restore those user accounts in your local Active Directory service. You can’t delete or restore them in Office 365.

Ref: [Delete or restore users](https://support.office.com/en-nz/article/Delete-or-restore-users-d5155593-3bac-4d8d-9d8b-f4513a81479e)